# In Testcafe, How can I distribute tests on multiple browsers

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Say I have 100 tests.
I want the first 50 tests to run on Chrome and the next 50 in Firefox.

I don’t want to hard code the test names.

Do we have any easy way of configuring such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish the tests somehow. One easy way could be using tags:

```
test
    .meta({ b: 'firefox' })
    ('Test 1', async t => { 

    // some test steps
});

test
    .meta({ b: 'chrome' })
    ('Test 2', async t => { 

    // some test steps
});
```

then you'd execute some in firefox and some on chrome by:

```
$ testcafe chrome tests/* --test-meta b=chrome && testcafe firefox tests/* --test-meta b=firefox
```

You can also use [`--fixture-meta`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--fixture-meta-keyvaluekey2value2). Or perhaps you can put all the tests you want to execute in a certain browser in one directory etc.

Comment: Is there any way we could randomize which tests to execute in a particular browser. Like with every run, the browser on which the a particular test ran would be different

Comment: Not easily, and not with TestCafe. The most straighforward solution that comes to mind is to execute all tests in one browser, and another time all in another browser. You'd still run the tests in various browsers.